# I am not able to connect tomcat in my centos browser but it starting in terminal

Tags: java, tomcat

When I typed `./startup.sh` i am getting:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ashok/apache-tomcat-7.0.56
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ashok/apache-tomcat-7.0.56
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ashok/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ashok/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ashok/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/home/ashok/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/bin/catalina.sh: line 319: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java/bin/java: No such file or directory
/home/ashok/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/bin/catalina.sh: line 319: exec: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Its clearly saying that. Try to understand the error message. The **JRE_HOME** should be  **/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/** not **/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java**

Answer (score 1):

Please add to your /etc/profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

Login and logout for it to take effect.

The advantage of this is that you do not have to update it everytime you update your Java.